# Rails 7 ActionText / rich_text null error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, richtext, actiontext

I'm trying to build a really simple backend only rails app with a post class. I can't seem to get my 'Posts' to persist because the rich_text field doesn't seem to be working. My actually class has more than this, the only error I'm encountering is around the rich_text. If I don't require this field I can save a post, but the rich_text is always null.

Post Class

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:create, :show, :update, :destroy]
  
  def create
    @post = Post.new params.require(:post).permit(:content)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

test:

```
  test "should save post with valid attributes" do
    post = Post.new(
      content: "<div>Sample Content</div>"
    )
  
    puts "DEBUG: content attribute before save: #{post.content.body.to_s.inspect}"
  
    assert post.save, "Could not save post with valid attributes. Errors: #{post.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
  end
```

Error

```
Error:
PostTest#test_should_save_post_with_valid_attributes:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "content" of relation "posts" violates not-null constraint
```

I've tried looking at the docs, reading some posts about this issue, and asking ChatGPT for help, but I'm not able to solve it.

Any tips for how to fix this?

I'm trying to save a post with rich_text. I've read a few other issues around rails 7 with rich_text but they made a lot of suggestions about fixing the front end and this is backend only. I've tried deleting everything and starting over. I've tried asking ChatGPT. No solution yet.

Comment: You should not have a `content` column in your `posts` table, please read the guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html

Comment: I don't understand. If I remove content from the post table I just end up with this error:


ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "posts" has no columns named "content".

Comment: The guide snoot, read the guide.